# Localized properties on a UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, localization

I have a problem with localizations and a `UserControl` in my Windows Phone 8 App on XAML and C#. Unfortunately I didn't find a helpful solution to my problem despite trying to fix it the whole weekend.

**The problem:**

I have a custom `UserControl`, which I use in MainPage.xaml. I tried to bind a localized string to the `IngredientName`, but I get:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException (Failed to assign to property)

This is **MyUserControl.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Name="myuc">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt_IngredientName />
</UserControl>
```

In the code-behind (**MyUserControl.xaml.cs**) I use the following lines to set and get values in the MainPage:

```
public string IngredientName
{
    get { return this.txt_ingredientName.Text; }
    set { this.txt_ingredientName.Text = value; }
}
```

In **MainPage.xaml** I call the UserControl the following way:

```
<local:MyUserControl IngredientName="Chocolate"/>
```

This works fine. But when I want to use a localized string:

```
IngredientName="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Chocolate, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

I get the error.

I read and tried a lot about Dependencies, Bindings, and so on, but I didn't get it work. Does anyone know to use localized strings on a UserControl the proper way? Or can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Binding` to work you need a `DependencyProperty`. Place the following code in `MyUserControl`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IngredientNameProperty
    = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IngredientName",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(HandleIngredientNameChanged));

public string IngredientName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(IngredientNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IngredientNameProperty, value); }
}

private static void HandleIngredientNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (MyUserControl) d;
    control.txt_ingredientName.Text = (string) e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: **Your great!** Thank you very much for your help, it works fine! I will do now some researchs on the DependencyProperty...;-)